# match_parent not working for ListView, if ListView is inside NestedScrollView

Tags: android, xml, listview, nestedscrollview

In my app I am using a `ListView` and it is inside a `NestedScrollView`. When I set `height` of the `ListView` to `match_parent` it does not cover the whole screen. I want that `ListView` to cover the whole screen.

My XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:isScrollContainer="false"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="1dp">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:divider="@null" />
        </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: can you pl share the screenshot of listview with data?

Comment: Sorry but my reputation is less. At least 10 reputation is needed to add screenshots.

Comment: As @Reza mentioned you should not use a scrollable view like listview inside another scollable view like scrollview. So why do you want listview to be inside NestedScrollView?

Comment: where are you using this nestedscrollview in other layout?... post it

Comment: @RajenRaiyarela I am developing the app with new Material design library. And i want my toolbar to hide when listview is scrolled. So NestedtedScrollView is mandatory for my app.

Comment: paste your main xml layout in your question

Comment: I am using it as a fragment for viewpager

Comment: check your fragment layuot ,that you are not using padding in your fragment layuot

Comment: Actually, the above xml file is fragment and it is directly added to the viewpager.

Comment: i mean, check its parent viewpager container's width and padding.

Comment: Everything is fine. If i add WebView instead of ListView. Then Webview is covering whole screen but not ListView

Comment: are you using custom row layout for list rows?

Comment: No actually i am parsing json for the list view objects

Comment: i mean,using custom adapter or default arrayadapter?

Comment: Using the default arrayadapter

Comment: you can try my personal suggestion, try to set the background color of above three views one by one and you can see which one is creating problem.

Comment: Okay i'll try. Thanks

Comment: Forget about nesting `ListView` in the `NestedScrollView`. Just use `RecyclerView` instead.

Comment: It will be a very long process. And i also don't know how to use recyclerview in place of listview

Comment: Please mark @amzer answer as the correct answer

Answer (score 43):

Add this to your NestedScrollView

```
android:fillViewport="true"
```

Comment: this should be an answer

Comment: i resorted to many hackery methods until i found this one line solution, many thanks!

Comment: the perfect one. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

android:fillViewport="true"

This makes the list view cover the entire device screen but in case there is much data, it does not enable scrolling.
[You can view its results from this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wl0xQ.jpg)

Answer (score -1):

i am not sure this will help you problem but i fix my problem like you with this solution

```
 <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:minHeight="@dimen/min_height"> //minimum height for listview
```

Comment: please try with remove Linear Layout above  listview or add "android:minHeight="@dimen/min_height" " in the Linear Layout